# How can I call a method of an object in a list iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, object, iterator

I have a list of Point objects in C++11 and I want to combine each point's string value into a longer string. I have a method to get the point as a string in a certain format, but I can't figure out how to call that method while iterating through the list.

This is my code:

```
  list<Point> points;
  string results = "";
  
  for (int i = 0; i < num_points; i++) {
    Point ptemp = Point(random01(), random01());
    points.push_back(ptemp);
    results += ptemp.getStr();
  }
  
  string log_output = "";
  string sep = ",";
  list<Point>::iterator iter;
  for (iter = points.begin(); iter != points.end(); ++iter) {
    // get the first three points in the log.txt format
    log_output += *iter.getRawStr(",") + " , ";  
  }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error: ‘std::__cxx11::list<Point>::iterator’ {aka ‘struct std::_List_iterator<Point>’} has no member named ‘getRawStr’
  177 |     log_output += *iter.getRawStr(",") + " , ";
```

I've tried taking away the asterisk, using to_string() instead, and reformatting the loop to use an increasing integer i with the iterator methods called separately inside the loop, but it still doesn't work. I've also tried researching it, but I've only seen `cout << *iter`, not how to specifically call methods from the iterator. What should I do?

Comment: `.` operator has higher precedence than `*`. You need `(*iter).getRawStr()` or `iter->getRawStr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of operator precedence. The `.` binds more tightly than `*`, so this

```
*iter.getRawStr(",")
```

is actually this

```
*(iter.getRawStr(","))
```

That is, it tries to call `getRawStr` on the *iterator* (not the thing it's pointing to), and then dereference the result. You want

```
(*iter).getRawStr(",")
```

which is equivalent<sup>[1]</sup> to

```
iter->getRawStr(",")
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Technically, `operator ->` can be overridden, so a pathological class might define it to do something different than unary `*`, but no normal, sane C++ class should do this.

Answer (score 1):

Either write

```
log_output += ( *iter ).getRawStr(",") + " , ";
```

or

```
log_output += iter->getRawStr(",") + " , ";
```

Otherwise this expression

```
*iter.getRawStr(",")
```

is equivalent to

```
* ( iter.getRawStr(",") )
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the `.` operator having higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, so the compiler looks for a member `getRawStr` in `std::list::iterator`. You need to use `()` to change this. Alternatively you could use a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) allowing you to skip the iterator-related code:

```
for(auto& point : points)
{
    log_output += point.getRawStr(",") + " , ";
}
```